# SET TIMEZONE em raw query

Tags: query, django, timezone, django-queryset

A raw query abaixo, apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
query = Resume.objects.raw("""
            SET TIMEZONE='America/Sao_Paulo';
            SELECT id, datetime_now FROM resume;
""")

raise AssertionError("database connection isn't set to UTC")
AssertionError: database connection isn't set to UTC
```

Se retirar o SET TIMEZONE o erro não ocorre.

O banco de dados está configurado da seguinte forma, no que tange ao timezone:

```
# show timezone;
     TimeZone      
-------------------
 America/Sao_Paulo
(1 row)
```

O settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = True
```

O que pode estar provocando isto?

Comment: pq vc tá usando comandos sql se vc pode usar o ORM do django? vc consegue pegar essas configurações do `settings.py` facilmente

Answer (score 0):

O problema ocorre quanto é declarado, no settings.py, a variável de ambiente:

```py
USE_TZ = True
```

Para utilizar cursor ou raw query, esta deve ser removida.